# Number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with the script below. If I download date from .json with lots of data in child I get error: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1. For example: `{"Parent": {"Child": {"1": "TRUE", "2": "FALSE"}, "Child2": {"1": "FALSE"}}}` If there is only one type, everything works fine. for example: `{"Parent": {"Child": {"1": "TRUE"}, "Child2": {"1": "FALSE"}}}`. The error persists when manually increasing the number of columns

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];
    
    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
  return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}

function insertJSON(){
  var aOneName = "id";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fileURL = "link to .json"
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL,{'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; 
  var toRows = rows[0].length;
  var toRows = toRows + 1;
  Logger.log("A2:A" + toRows);
  Logger.log(rows);
  var rowsflate = flatten(rows);
  var rowstocols  = chunkArray(rowsflate, 1);
  Logger.log(rowstocols);
  sheet.getRange("A2:A" + toRows).setValues(rowstocols); 
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(aOneName); 
  
  var headers = json[rows[0][2]];
  Logger.log(headers);
  var getHeaders = [Object.keys(headers)];
  Logger.log(getHeaders);
  sheet.getRange(1,4,getHeaders.length,getHeaders[0].length).setValues(getHeaders); 
  content
  var content = [];
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
  var temp2 = [Object.values(json[rows[0][i]])];// Retrieve values to be split.
  content.push(flatten(temp2));
  }
  Logger.log(content);
  var columncount1= rows[0].length;
  Logger.log(columncount1);
  var columncount2 = getHeaders[0].length;
  Logger.log(columncount2);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,columncount1,columncount2).setValues(content); 
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UkjR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjqnh.png
```

Comment: My suspicion is something in your content array is not symmetrical.  For each row you must have the same number of columns.  And may not be the size indicated by columncount1 and 2.

Comment: I set the speakers "manually", it did not help. [SS](https://prnt.sc/oUmF2GmC1JY) This happens when I manually rearrange the value of the columns. Suddenly the values change, but the data appears anyway [SS2](https://prnt.sc/VoqALuttuWcY0). So I have a data loading error that only has 1 child but 2 childs is already showing ... I have no idea how to fix it. I searched half of google and asked support.google but they replied that I have to add `content [0] .length` which I tried before writing to them.

Comment: You can try to change the last line this way: `sheet.getRange(1, 1, content.length, content[0].length).setValues(content);`